# What does "potted" mean in "Potted Potter"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

There is a play called [Potted Potter](http://www.pottedpotter.com/) which is a parody about all seven Harry Potter books.

What is the meaning of *potted* in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means shortened or compressed. For example, [*potted history*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22potted%20history%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1995,cd_max:1997&lr=lang_en) is a frequently used phrase that means a history that is abridged.

As the website you link to says:

> All seven Harry Potter books in seventy hilarious minutes!

So [Harry] Potter has been potted.

[Potted](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/potted) in this sense is recorded as chiefly British usage.

Comment: [Some dictionaries](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/potted) also gives the meaning 'intoxicated; drunk' which works figuratively for a comic parody.

Answer (score 2):

Abridged.

Literally, a method of cooking or preserving (in a pot), but often used to refer to a condensed form of e.g. a book.